# Middleman and Sinatra Contact Form rendering template

Tags: css, html, sinatra, haml

I'm trying to create a middleman site with a contact form using sinatra and pony gem

I'm having problems getting middleman and sinatra to play nicely together

THE ISSUE:

"
My Contact From is **not rendering my header and footer** and also **does not like it when I try to include view helpers** like = link_to tags When I try that I get this error

undefined method `link_to' for

Its also not picking up my stylesheets
"

Heres my Mailer.rb get method

```
class MailForms < Sinatra::Base
  set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root)}
  get '/' do
    haml :contact, :layout => :'/contact'
  end
end
```

and it lives in source/mailer.rb

when I go to website.com/contact.hml

1. I get the form but it has no header or footer all my other pages have them and is working
2. I can't use = link_to tags or image tags i get an undefined method error
3. Its also not picking up my styles

heres my config.rb

```
 require 'source/mailer'
 map('/contact.html') do
   run MailForms
 end

 set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'

 set :js_dir, 'javascripts'

 set :images_dir, 'images'

 set :relative_links, true

 configure :build do
   activate :relative_assets
 end
```

heres my layout.haml with my stylesheet link

```
 !!!
 %html
   %head
     %meta{charset: "utf-8"}
     %meta{content: "IE=edge,chrome=1", "http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible"}
     %title= current_page.data.title || "Auto Tint Specalist"
     %link{href: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css", rel: "stylesheet"}
     = stylesheet_link_tag "normalize", "all"
     %script{src: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"}
     = javascript_include_tag  "all"
   %body{class: page_classes}
     = partial 'layouts/header'
     = yield
     = partial 'layouts/footer'
```

all my styles are in all.scss in the stylesheets folder